# Is System.IO.Pipes namespace available in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

using **System.IO.Pipes** namespace is giving errors in UWP app. Is this namespace available for [uwp](/questions/tagged/uwp) c# project?

`NamedPipeClientStream` class is used in my project. In order to use this class, I m trying to use this pipes namespace but it gives errors while using it.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185496.aspx

Comment: No, it is not there, but you should be able to include it: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.Pipes/

Comment: It seems the `System.IO.Pipes` is not supported in UWP.